# Terminate a 'sleeping' thread

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a task I want to run in the background and not interrupt the GUI thread to check for new program versions.

When the application starts, it immediately queues a thread to wait 15 seconds then execute the remainder of the code. If the check is *manually* triggered before the 15 seconds are up, the existing automatic thread should be terminated. If the application is closed at any point, any remaining threads should be terminated as soon as possible.

I use 2 minutes in the example below for easier debugging.

My issue right now is that no combination that I've tried using  `WaitFor`, `Terminate`, `FreeOnTerminate`, and `OnTerminated` will get the desired result. Either `Destroy` isn't called and I get memory leaks, the application hangs when terminating a thread, or I get `Cannot terminate externally created thread` exceptions.

Thread code

```pascal
unit unCheckThread;

interface

uses SysUtils, Classes, SyncObjs, Dialogs;

type
  TCheckThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FDelayEvent: TEvent;
    FDelay: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(const ADelay: Integer);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TCheckThread }

constructor TCheckThread.Create(const ADelay: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := False;

  FDelay := ADelay;
  FDelayEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
end;

destructor TCheckThread.Destroy;
begin
  FDelayEvent.Free;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TCheckThread.Execute;
begin
  FDelayEvent.WaitFor(MSecsPerSec * FDelay);

  { if another thread has checked while waiting for the delay, cancel this check }
  if Terminated then Exit;

  { some long running code }
  Sleep(10000);

  if Terminated then Exit;

  Synchronize(
    procedure()
    begin
      MessageDlg('Thread completed', mtConfirmation, [mbOK], 0);
    end);
end;

procedure TCheckThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FDelayEvent.SetEvent;
end;

end.
```

UI

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, unCheckThread, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    AThread: TCheckThread;
    procedure onterminate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(AThread) then begin
    AThread.Terminate;
//    AThread.WaitFor; // ?
  end;

  AThread := TCheckThread.Create(0); // start immediately
  AThread.OnTerminate := onterminate;
  AThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Assigned(AThread) then begin
    AThread.Terminate;
//    AThread.WaitFor; // ??
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AThread := TCheckThread.Create(SecsPerMin * 2); // wait for 2 mintues before starting
end;

procedure TForm1.onterminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(AThread);
end;

end.
```

Comment: **1.** Use `FormDestroy` instead of `FormClose`. **2.** Remove `OnTerminate` event handler. **3.** Instead of requesting termination and waiting for thread use `FreeAndNil(AThread)` both in `FormDestroy` and `Button1Click`. Freeing a thread from the main thread will call appropriate routines for you. **4.** Don't let the tread sleep. It won't be able to respond to cancellation. You've already used manual reset event as a signal for cancellation in the initial delay. Do the same later on - regularly check the state of the event.

Comment: @PeterWolf "*Instead of requesting termination and waiting for thread use `FreeAndNil(AThread)`*" - That is VERY BAD advice. `Free`'ing a running `TThread` is NOT SAFE. ALWAYS *explicitly* request termination and wait for termination to complete BEFORE `Free`'ing the `TThread`. That is the SAFE way to go.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the adjustment. I'm am aware of some issues that can be caused be `Free`'ing a running thread. On the other hand `Destroy` does more than `Terminate` and `WaitFor` the thread. It also `Resume`'s suspended thread and `Yield`'s until it starts, if it wasn't started. Therefore `Terminate` & `WaitFor` is not sufficient in all scenarios. I'd be interested in further reading on how to shut down threads gracefully in Delphi and what are gotchas. Most notably it's destroying thread's fields before calling `inherited` in overridden destructor, I'd say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't interrupt a `Sleep()`, so that is not a good choice for debugging, especially for long intervals. You should use `FDelayEvent.WaitFor()` instead.  That way, the thread can "wake up" quickly when it is being terminated.

Also, instead of calling `Synchronize()` at the end of `Execute()`, you should use the `OnTerminate` event instead for any operations you need when the thread is finished.  `OnTerminate` is already synchronized with the main UI thread.

For instance, you can use `OnTerminate` to set your `AThread` variable to `nil` when that thread is terminated, so that your `Assigned(AThread)` check doesn't fail.  You are already trying to do this, however you can't *safely* `Free` a thread from inside its `OnTerminate` event handler, so you might consider using `FreeOnTerminate=True` instead, or at least delay the `Free` until after the handler exits.

For that matter, I would not suggest creating a delayed thread at app startup to begin with.  Use a `TTimer` instead.  When its `OnTimer` event is fired, THEN create a non-delayed thread.  If the user triggers a manual check, simply disable the timer.  This way, you don't waste resources creating a thread that just sits idle, and you don't have to worry about syncing multiple threads to each other.

With that said, try something more like this:

```pascal
unit unCheckThread;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TCheckThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOnTerminate: TNotifyEvent);
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

{ TCheckThread }

constructor TCheckThread.Create(AOnTerminate: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
  OnTerminate := AOnTerminate;
end;

procedure TCheckThread.Execute;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  { some long running code }
  for I := 1 to 20 do
  begin
    if Terminated then Exit;
    Sleep(500);
  end;
end;

end.
```

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, unCheckThread;

const
  WM_FREE_THREAD = WM_APP + 1;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    AThread: TCheckThread;
    procedure ThreadFinished(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StartThread;
    procedure StopThread;
    procedure WMFreeThread(var Message: TMessage); message WM_FREE_THREAD;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartThread;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Interval := 120000; // wait for 2 minutes before starting
  Timer1.Enabled = True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StopThread;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartThread;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  if not Assigned(AThread) then
  begin
    AThread := TCheckThread.Create(ThreadFinished);
    Button1.Enabled := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.StopThread;
begin
  if Assigned(AThread) then
  begin
    AThread.OnTerminate := nil;
    AThread.Terminate;
    AThread.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(AThread);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AThread := nil;

  // in 10.2 Tokyo and later, you can use TThread.ForceQueue() instead...
  // TThread.ForceQueue(nil, Sender.Free);
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_FREE_THREAD, 0, LPARAM(Sender));

  MessageDlg('Thread completed', mtConfirmation, [mbOK], 0);
  Button1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  StartThread;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMFreeThread(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  TObject(Message.LParam).Free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'll wait to get back to work to test this one out, but this definitely seems like the right approach. I hadn't considered a timer, but that's a pretty obvious simple fix

Comment: This was a great help, thank you. Are you able to elaborate at all on why a thread can't safely be freed in it's `OnTerminate` handler? I've changed to your suggestions `FreeOnTerminate=True` and `AThread=nil` in `OnTerminate`, but for my own benefit, I tried `AThread.Free` which just freezes the app when the thread terminates.

Comment: @Ranky you can't free the thread in its `OnTerminate` event for the same reason you can't free any object in its own events - the RTL still needs access to the object after the event handler exits, so if you free it then bad things happen. Doubly so for `TThread`, because its destructor will wait for the thread to terminate if it hasn't yet, so freeing it inside its `OnTerminate` event will cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

If:

- for whatever reason, you want to keep the structure of your code ...
- when you said "*If the application is closed at any point, any remaining threads should be terminated as soon as possible.*" -> it means that we do not really care about the result of any process being run/worked on by the thread ...

Then:

- **this won't be** a **"clean"**, academic, software engineering kind of way
- this is just an alternative to simply get things done (targeting 2 objectives: "killing"/terminating a thread and avoiding memory leaks)

1. Keep your line of code below.

   `FreeOnTerminate := False;`
2. "Kill"/terminate the thread (regardless of its state).

   `TerminateThread(AThread.Handle, 0);`
3. `TForm1` has/owns `AThread`, and because your code may re-create `AThread` (in `FormCreate` then in `Button1Click`), free the thread every time right after it has been terminated (currently, you do this in `Button1Click` and `FormClose`). Just in case you do `if Assigned(AThread)` anywhere else, use `FreeAndNil` (it frees `AThread` and sets it to `nil`, this way `Assigned(AThread)` can correctly return `False` when the thread has been terminated and freed using your code structure).

   `FreeAndNil(AThread);`

The `TerminateThread` method (above) needs `Winapi.Windows` (which you have had in the uses list of your `Unit1`). It replaces `AThread.Terminate`.

It would look like below:

```
  if Assigned(AThread) then begin
    TerminateThread(AThread.Handle, 0);
    FreeAndNil(AThread);
  end;
```

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong approach. Never resort to `TerminateThread()` when there are better solutions. Even Microsoft advises staying away from `TerminateThread()`, and they invented it. Sure, IN THIS EXAMPLE, it is fairly harmless, but as the code evolves and the thread *actually does real work*, using `TerminateThread()` becomes more dangerous to use.